# How to Nest a WHILE LOOP

Tags: sql

I am having trouble with these WHILE loops.  I want my query to look at each Product_ID and count how many times it was purchased each day for the first 12 days after it arrived.  Inventory items vary wildly from 20,000 to 140,000 different items in stock depending on the date, season, etc. I want to display day01 [COUNT of that PiD Sold], day02, etc.  I was thinking a nested loop might be the answer, but I am open to suggestions ……advice?

Note: Right now the query seems broken and runs forever.
  Please excuse the formating.

```
              DECLARE
    @Item_Num01 int,
    @Item_Num02 int,
    @Nomenclature varchar(255),
    @PiD varchar(255),
    @MadeOn datetime,
    @TimeSpan int,   
    @date datetime,
    @count int

           SELECT * FROM TABLE_02 ORDER BY ItemName ASC


    SET @Item_Num01 = 1
    SELECT @Item_Num02 = MAX(INVEN_ID) FROM TABLE_02
    CREATE TABLE TABLE_03(ItemName nvarchar(255), Prod_ID varchar(255), Shipped_Date datetime, 
    Time_Span int, Day int, OrdersCount int, INVEN_ID int)

    WHILE @Item_Num01 <= @Item_Num02
BEGIN
           SET @Nomenclature = 0
    SET @PiD = 0
    SET @MadeOn = 0
    SET @TimeSpan = 0
    SET @count = 0

    SELECT @Nomenclature = ItemName FROM TABLE_02 WHERE INVEN_ID = @Item_Num01
    SELECT @PiD = Product_ID FROM TABLE_02 WHERE INVEN_ID = @Item_Num01
    SELECT @MadeOn = Shipped_Date FROM TABLE_02 WHERE INVEN_ID = @Item_Num01
    SELECT @TimeSpan = Time_Span FROM TABLE_02 WHERE INVEN_ID = @Item_Num01
        SET @date = @MadeOn
       WHILE @date < DATEADD(DAY,12,@MadeOn)
    BEGIN
    SELECT @count = COUNT(INV_STK.Product_ID)
    FROM INV_STK
        WHERE INV_STK.PRODUCT_ID = @PiD
        AND CONVERT(DATE,SoldDate) = CONVERT(DATE,@date)

    INSERT INTO TABLE_03
    VALUES (@Nomenclature, @PiD, @MadeOn, @TimeSpan,DATEDIFF(dd,@MadeOn,@date+@TimeSpan, @count, @Item_Num01)

    SET @date = DATEADD(DAY,1,@date)
 END
    SET @Item_Num01 = @Item_Num01 + 1
  END

SELECT * FROM TABLE_03 ORDER BY INVEN_ID, Day ASC
```

Thank You

Comment: Please tag only a single DBMS, MySql or SqlServer, but not both.  Answers may depend on the platform specified.

Comment: _Please excuse the formating_ - No. If you want us to help, you should format it properly and make it easy to read.

Comment: You're best off providing example data and desired results rather than your broken query. A while loop is unlikely to be the best way.

Comment: You need to search to learn about pivot tables, which would eliminate most (if not all) of your code. Where to look would depend on the DBMS you're actually using, which you have not indicated.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. Taking a different approach sounds like a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Without actual sample data, this is what I came up with:

```
SELECT t.ItemName, t.Product_ID AS Prod_ID, t.Shipped_Date, t.Time_Span, d.NumDays AS [Day], count(i.Product_ID) AS OrdersCount, t.INVEN_ID
FROM table_02 t
    CROSS JOIN (
        SELECT NumDays
        FROM (
            SELECT ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY name) NumDays
            FROM master..spt_values
            ) a
        WHERE NumDays <= 12
    ) d
    LEFT JOIN INV_STK i ON i.Product_ID = t.Product_ID
        and CONVERT(DATE,i.SoldDate) = CONVERT(DATE,DATEADD(DAY,d.NumDays,t.Shipped_Date))
GROUP BY t.ItemName, t.Product_ID, t.Shipped_Date, t.Time_Span, d.NumDays, t.INVEN_ID
```

Essentially, you want to make sure that you have all 12 days, so generate artificial rows with an inner join, and use the day value in the dateadd function for your left join to the inventory table. After that, it's all aggregation and grouping. This should server your purposes. I'll need sample input and desired output to refine any further, though.

Comment: Thanks Jazz, if I don't get anywhere my next request will include sample data, sample output, and proper formatting. If I'm going to ask for assistance the least I can do is make helping me as easy as possible.